# Dynamic lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

With dynamic create can I set body after doinit in c:customcomponent will finish

```
 $A.createComponent("c:customcomponent",{idi: id,

       function(components, status, errorMessage){
    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
        var message = components[0];
        message.set("v.body", message);
    }

}
},
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the scenario, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, so. I trying display modal after load to them all information from apex. I don't know how much time apex will need to calculate. But sometimes I call to check information 3 time per 5 minutes